# Sprockets //= require with jsbundling-rails (esbuild) - how to include JS provided by gem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Basically, exactly as the title says. I have a gem installed that gives me some JS to use. This wasn't a problem before as I was using Sprockets + Assets pipeline.

Now, I migrated to jsbundling-rails and have literally no idea how to include that JS code provided by gem. I've spent like 10 hours searching and no luck so far.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The gem would have to have a js package that can be installed with yarn/npm so that it can be imported in *application.js*. If it doesn't, you can setup a js file to be processed only by *sprockets*, like in the old days.

Add another javascript entry point that will skip *esbuild* and will be processed only by *sprockets*.

Update manifest:

```js
// app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link custom.js
```

Add `//= require` directive:

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/custom.js

//= require gem_javascript
```

Add it to layout:

```html
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->

<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "custom", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

---

Alternatively, instead of using *//= require* add *gem_javascript* to `javascript_include_tag`:

```html
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "gem_javascript", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

Might have to add it to manifest as well for precompilation:

```
// app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link gem_javascript
```

Comment: There is not an upvote big enough for this!