# Shakapacker, Rails, React: Doesn't load up app/assets non-react javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, shakapacker

I updated my app to Rails 7 and moved it from webpacker to shakapacker.

It is mostly a react frontend, with some old pages in haml with jquery listening on js files in app/assets.

Shakapacker and react front end is working properly, the rails views load (they don't even need webpacker running), but the jquery listeners are not running/listening to the rails views.

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Is loading up, I can see through logging to the console.

The file looks like this:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker 2')
// = require jquery-3.3.1.min
//= require popper
//= require rails-ujs
//= require cable
//= require jquery-ui
//= require activestorage
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-select
//= require moment
//= require tempusdominus-bootstrap-4
//= require jquery.easy-autocomplete.min
//= require jquery.slimscroll.min
//= require patch_modal
//= require_tree
```

React app is loaded up when rails routes using the react frontend are hit with:
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'react_app', crossorigin: "anonymous" %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'react_app', crossorigin: "anonymous" %>

Is there something else I need to configure to get my js files in app/assets/javascripts/*.js to compile with shakapacker?

I felt like it just worked with webpacker, I also tried a few other compilers (jsbuild, vite) and it was fine as well. I had to stop with them for other issues on my React side.

Any advice or pointers are super appreciated. I feel like I have spent way too long on making Rails 7 happy with the front end.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```rb
app/
├─ assets/              # used by sprockets-rails
│  └─ javascripts/      # not used in rails 7 by default
│     └─ application.js # javascript_include_tag "application"
│
└─ javascript/          # used by shakapacker and other js bundlers
   ├─ packs/            # webpack entries
   │  └─ application.js # javascript_pack_tag "application"
   │
   └─ application.js    # or this one (depending on `source_entry_path` in config/webpacker.yml)
```

*Shakapacker* should not process `assets/javascripts/application.js`, because it doesn't know how to process `//= require` directives. They are handled by *sprockets*.

To load *assets/javascripts/application.js*, add this to your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

and double check `manifest.js`, it should have *application.js*:

```
//= link application.js
```

*[Sprockets //= require with jsbundling-rails (esbuild) - how to include JS provided by gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72305291/sprockets-require-with-jsbundling-rails-esbuild-how-to-include-js-provid/72367920#72367920)*

---

*Sprockets* directives are processed only at the top of the file:

```
// This is processed by sprockets and popper is required.
//= require popper
console.log("loaded")
// After any code, it is a regular comment, nothing happens.
//= require popper
```

*https://github.com/rails/sprockets#directives*

Comment: I had most of this set up already (I guess from Rails 6), but when I add the gem sprockets, restart I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at application.debug-f2...:1)

Comment: Moving up! Added gem 'babel-transpiler', and now that is resolved. Now working on $ is not defined. <(o)><(o)>