# Can I use Turbo in rails 7 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, turbo

I recently upgraded my site from rails 3.1 to rails 7.0.5.1. Now I have lot of legacy javascript code which I want to include via asset pipeline and avoid importmaps. But to use turbo/ turbolinks, I get a message that to use turbo, you should have importmaps or webpacker.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is a question ... but to give you a "not answer" you might be better off creating a new directory/repository with a rails 7 install, and then copy in the missing bits from your existing one in order to get rails 7 enabled turbo

Answer (score 1):

You still need to have `turbo-rails` gem. Skip the `turbo:install` command, it doesn't do [much](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/lib/install/turbo_with_importmap.rb). Install it yourself:

```html
<%= javascript_include_tag("turbo", type: "module") %>
or
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@hotwired/turbo-rails@7.3.0/app/assets/javascripts/turbo.min.js"></script>
```

For module scripts you might need this: *https://github.com/guybedford/es-module-shims*

You've got *Turbo*! In addition, if you want to use [broadcasts](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/app/models/concerns/turbo/broadcastable.rb) you'll need to set up *redis* (*postgres adapter does work for small [~8kb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) streams*).

Note that you can have importmaps, and esbuild, and some plain files from sprockets all together:

```rb
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>            # importmap-rails
<%= javascript_include_tag("esbuild") %>    # jsbundling-rails
<%= javascript_include_tag("my_old_js") %>  # sprockets
```

If you get an error about precompilation, add files to `manifest.js`:
*https://stackoverflow.com/a/72367920/207090*